# Uniform convergence as $\epsilon\to 0^+$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Reading some lectures on Hamilton-Jacobi PDE theory I found some terminology that I really don't understand.

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $u_\epsilon:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function for $\epsilon>0$. Consider a sequence of function $(u_\epsilon)$ and let $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

What does $u_\epsilon$ converges uniformly to $u$ as $\epsilon\to 0^+$ means?

I mean, I know what uniformly convergence means for a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ as $n\to +\infty$, but I really don't understand this terminology.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{u_h\}_h$ be a family of functions indexed by $h\in S\subset (0,\infty)$. We say that $u_h\to u$ uniformly as $h\to 0^+$ if for a given $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in\Omega}|u_h(x)-u(x)| < \varepsilon
$$
for all $h\in S\cap(0,\delta)$.

---

*Remark*: Using this definition, we can see that $u_n\to u$ uniformly in the usual sense iff $\hat u_h\to u$ uniformly as $h\to 0^+$, provided that we take our index set to be $S=\{1,\frac 12,\frac 13,\dots\}$ and
$$
\hat u_{1/n} := u_n.
$$

Comment: That's completely clear! Thank you so much!